# Bulk inserting specific values using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, dictionary

I have the following table in my postgres database:

```
create table num1(col1 bigint, col2 bigint, col3 bigint, col4 bigint);
create table dictionary (id bigint, value varchar);
```

The example data in table1 is:

```
5 3 4 2 
9 6 8 2
1 7 8 3
```

Now I want to bulk insert all the values present in col2 in num1 into dictionary(it is an existing table and already contains values) into its id column. So that my dictionary contains the following values:

```
3  str3
6  str6
7  str
```

Here value column of dictionary contains "str"+col2 form of values.

Is it possible to do so in postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually do the insert -

```
insert into dictionary (id, value)
values (3, 'str3'), (6, 'str6'), (7, 'str7');
```

To insert from the result of a query -

```
insert into dictionary (id, value)
select distinct col2, 'str' || col2::text
from num1
```

Comment: thanks for replying..i want to pick distinct values from col2 from num1 and insert them into dictionary

Comment: Easy!  Just put distinct in the select query...updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO dictionary(id,value) values(1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc')